# SOLR field query skip records if..statement

Tags: solr

I have a lot of products in solr, all of them with a field_code and a field_stock, and i want to exclude records like this, with a field query.

```
-field_code:(A OR B) OR (-(field_code:C AND field_stock:false) AND -(field_code:D AND field_stock:false))
```

so, all products with field_code either A or B

OR

all products with field_code C OR D and both not in stock, shoudl be excluded

everything else should be returned ?

Update:

I have added another field to the query, and it does not work.

i have `field_code` , `field_stock` and the new `field_type`

I need to remove all products from the query, that:

does not have: field_code = A OR B OR C OR D
and
field_stock = 0 (-field_stock:1)
AND
field_type = 'joe'

So something like:

SELECT * FROM table WHERE (field_code NOT IN (A,B,C,D) and field_type = 'joe' AND field_stock=0)

So that all records is returned, but the above ? Make any sense ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a negative query you have to subtract the query from something - just having a negative query won't do anything by itself (if you ONLY have a single, negative query without any boolean operators Solr helpfully prefixes the set of all documents in front, since that's probably what you meant).

Something like this would probably match what you're describing:

```
(*:* -field_code:(A OR B)) OR 
(*:* -(field_code:(C OR D) AND field_stock:false))
```

I'm assuming that `field_code` is multi-valued, since the second term after `OR` won't make sense otherwise.

Comment: Thank you, will test out 2mrw, Can you tell what *:* does

Comment: `*:*` is the set that represents all documents in the index - i.e. `q=*:*` would give you all documents present.

Comment: It's kind of hard to parse what you're asking - if you want documents that match all terms (which is what you wrote in your description) `*:* -(field_code:(A OR B OR C OR D) AND field_stock:0 AND field_type = 'joe')` should give you all documents that doesn't match all those. But in your SQL example you're asking for all documents that doesn't have A OR B OR C OR D, but do have field_stock:0 and field_type:joe. In that case you can take the terms that _do_ match out and replace `*:*` with them: `field_stock:0 field_type:joe -field_code:(A OR B OR C OR D)`

Comment: MatsLindh, sorry my bad english, i want to get everything out, BUT all records with stock:0 AND type:joe and not in code: A OR B OR C OR D
And stock have to be -field_stock:1 because its not set if it's not 1.

Comment: Given that you actually mean and and not that either field means that it should be excluded, `*:* -(field_code:(A OR B OR C OR D) AND (*:* -field_stock:[* TO *]) AND field_type:joe)` should work as far as I can parse? Depending on your need you might be able to move either of those ANDs out (i.e. if you don't want any documents included that isn't in stock anyway, regardless of the field code).